# Could these be Mycetozoa?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found this on a forest in Mexico City. It was kind of a warm day (around 15°C). It had been raining a few days prior and it was quite humid, but not suffocating.

This orange thing was on top of a rotting tree. I thought it could be *Dictydiaethalium*... maybe.

When I moved it it produced an orange slime.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your second species ID request (i.e., Lycogala epidendrum) should be asked in a separate question. In general, please do not combine multiple species into a single ID question. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a [slime mold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold) perhaps. See [here](http://www.ojibway.ca/redslime.jpg) for a picture of *Tubifera ferruginosa*, a visually similar looking species. EDIT: actually I see you suggest Dictydiaethalium, so you're thinking alogn the same lines as me. I'm no mycologist, so I'll leave the details up to someone else to figure out / answer